# Windows Installer

Tags: installation

I have a Windows 7 laptop (Lenovo T430u) and have tried to install Ubuntu alongside Windows using the Windows Installer. It works fine and I can log into Ubuntu once the install finishes. However once I restart the PC and select Ubuntu at boot it goes into what appears to be the Linux command line rather than booting to the Ubuntu login screen. I've tried re-installing using the Windows installer but I get the same error/problem. I've used Ubuntu on my previous laptop using the installer with no problem.

Any ideas greatly appreciated, bearing in mind that I'm not technical.

David Thomas

Comment: Which Ubuntu release did you install?  What happens with you type `sudo startx` at the prompt?

Comment: Is your laptop uses UEFI or BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about Wubi (the Windows installer), it is probably a good idea to not use that type of installer on your machine. With the information you've provided, it sounds like the graphics card could be the issue, and the Lenovo T430u has integrated Intel HD Graphics 4000 in it, which I know to be supported by Ubuntu. With that being said, there are two things you can do (neither of which require being that tech savvy). Install Ubuntu from a DVD, or install Ubuntu from a USB drive. First and foremost, [download the Ubuntu ISO file](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) onto Windows 7 and follow Ubuntu.com's [user-friendly instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) for either USB or DVD installation. I would love to help you more, but with the information you've provided, direct-media installation of Ubuntu just might be the ticket.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you. I'll download it to a USB drive. I think you are probably correct about the graphics card. I used Wubi  before on a T410i Thinkpad and had no problem.